# Petición GET no se lleva a acabo

Tags: c, http, socket

Hola tengo el siguiente código:

```
int http()
{
    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd, bytes, sent, total, portno = 80;

    char *host = "ejemplo.com";
    char *message = "GET /scripts/newdate.php?nombre=test HTTP/1.1";

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    server = gethostbyname(host);

    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");

    total = strlen(message);
    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,message+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

y el código se ejecuta sin problemas pero la petición no se lleva a cabo (me consta) no me devuelve ningún error ni nada ¿Alguna idea de que puede pasar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el protocolo [HTTP 1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html)

> ```
> Request       = Request-Line
>               *(( general-header
>               | request-header
>               | entity-header ) CRLF)
>               CRLF
>               [ message-body ]
> ```

Resumiento: te faltan 2 ``` \r``\n ``` al final de la solicitud.

```
char *message = "GET /scripts/newdate.php?nombre=test HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
                                                           // ^^
```

Tal y como lo muestras, el servidor se queda esperando **eternamente** que completes la solicitud.